# hide status bar in landscape mode leave a blank space when rotating

Tags: iphone, hide, statusbar

My application support to display some screen in landscape mode, and in landscape mode, I set to hide the status bar to get mode space to display data.

The problem is while hiding the status bar and rotate screen, it leave a white pace at status bar position until the screen is rotated completely as below screenshot.

[image] 
I guess that steps of operations when rotating screen are:
1. hide status bar
2. rotate screen
3. resize screen to take place of status bar.

So until the screen is rotated completely, user still can see the white space, it is not good and I want to do something such as: set color for that blank space to black, or set animation to hide that blank space but unlucky!

So, does anyone have solution to resolve this, please help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should make the size of view 320 * 480. as you might have hidden the statusbar but the size of view will be 320 * 460(default)

Check out this one.

Comment: It is work well, thanks! but I found an other way to achieve this by set window background color to black in ApplicationDelegate so now that blank space is in black =)

Comment: that is not proper way to do. as it may in future create another problem. but it's nice your work done.

Comment: Yes, I already thought about your solution before, but after resizing the frame, the framework would resize it again after rotating. So I decided to set background of window to black instead. Thanks